# Excel VB Count till Change

Tags: excel, vbscript

I don't do much with VB and need some help to count/tally up the number of instances of a given value.
 Data is in Column A and sorted by the value so all results are together just need a ongoing count till value changes or cell is blank.

Example of Sheet

[image]

```
Sub Rec_Label()
Path = "%UserProfile%"
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
fullpath = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(Path)
'Create lines for number of labels based on Column "G"

 ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=ActiveSheet
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim vRows As Long, v As Long
 On Error Resume Next
 Dim ir As Long, mrows As Long, lastcell As Range
 Set lastcell = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
 mrows = lastcell.Row
 For ir = mrows To 2 Step -1
  If Not IsNumeric(Cells(ir, 7)) Then
   Cells(ir, 1).EntireRow.Delete
  ElseIf Cells(ir, 1).Value > 1 Then
   v = Cells(ir, 1).Value - 1
   Rows(ir + 1).Resize(v).Insert Shift:=xlDown
   Rows(ir).EntireRow.AutoFill Rows(ir). _
     EntireRow.Resize(rowsize:=v + 1), xlFillCopy
   ElseIf Cells(ir, 1).Value < 1 Then
      Cells(ir, 1).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
  Next ir

'Fill-in Count based on column A
```

Comment: You need describe what you have done so far, including the VB code you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a subroutine which will perform the function you want. Note that it assumes the data is in A2:n and the desired result is to be in B2:n. Hopefully it is pretty obvious how to integrate it into your overall code.

```
Sub CountValues()
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Last As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
Dim V As String

Last = 0
Row = 2
Count = 1
V = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value
Do While V <> ""
    If Int(V) <> Last Then
        Count = 1
        Last = Int(V)
    Else
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 2).Value = Count
    Row = Row + 1
    V = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks perfect i can move as needed from here. I am very entry level at this stuff. Wish work would send me to some classes.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I've learnt an amazing amount from the people on stackoverflow but some formal training would have been so much better.

Answer (score 0):

In your `B2`, you can use this and drag down:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)
```

Comment: This is only part of a Larger Script that is being done to create records and then do a Mail Merge. Want to get it in the Script so other users don't have figure anything out.

Comment: @TherriaFernandez - Why not just use the `Worksheetfunction.Countif()` then and do it that way? Otherwise, if you need exactly the VBA to do this, can you post the relevant script where you would enter this?

Comment: Here is what i have so far.'Create lines for number of labels based on Column "G"
  
  ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=ActiveSheet
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim vRows As Long, v As Long
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim ir As Long, mrows As Long, lastcell As Range
  Set lastcell = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
  mrows = lastcell.Row
  For ir = mrows To 2 Step -1
    If Not IsNumeric(Cells(ir, 7)) Then
       Cells(ir, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf Cells(ir, 1).Value > 1 Then
       v = Cells(ir, 1).Value - 1

Comment: @TherriaFernandez can you please edit that in to your original post? It's hard to read code in a comment.  Thanks!